# Why does sortedDictionary need so much overhead?

Tags: c#, memory-management, sorteddictionary

```
long b = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
SortedDictionary<int, int> sd = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    sd.Add(i, i+1);
}
long a = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
Console.WriteLine((a - b));            
int reference = sd[10];
```

output (32 bit):

```
280108
```

output (64 bit):

```
480248
```

Storing the ints alone (in an array) would require about 80000.

Comment: because it's a tree. there are also SortedList and a plain List which happens to be sorted (make sure to insert items in their proper place)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses `TreeSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. The tree uses `Node<T>` and obviously it uses references between nodes, so in addition to each key and value you will have references to left and right nodes as well as some additional properties. `Node<T>` is a class so each instance  has the traditional overhead of a reference type. Furthermore, each node also stores a boolean called `IsRed`.

According to WinDbg/SOS the size of a single node on 64 bits in 48 bytes so 10000 of them will take up at least 480000 bytes.

```
0:000> !do 0000000002a51d90 
Name:            System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1+Node[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]], mscorlib]]
MethodTable: 000007ff000282c8
EEClass:     000007ff00133b18
Size:        48(0x30) bytes     <== Size of a single node
File:            C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value     Name
000007feeddfd6e8  4000624       18       System.Boolean  1 instance                0     IsRed
000007feee7fd3b8  4000625       20 ...Int32, mscorlib]]  1 instance 0000000002a51db0 Item
000007ff000282c8  4000626        8 ...lib]], mscorlib]]  0 instance 0000000002a39d90 Left
000007ff000282c8  4000627       10 ...lib]], mscorlib]]  0 instance 0000000002a69d90 Right
```

Comment: Does it really need this overhead for it's functionality?

Comment: @Willem: I guess the real question is; do you need all the functionality of SortedDictionary. If not there are options that take up less space. See the Remarks section of the documentation for a list of characteristics of SortedDictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on the implementation of SortedDictionary class and nothing to do with the .net runtime or CLR. You can implement your own sorted dictionary and control what and how much is allocated. Probably SortedDictionary implementation is not much efficient in terms of memory allocation.